# Using jQuery for Action Listeners on a Search Form in a Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, actionlistener

I've been trying to properly add an action event listener for a dropdown menu in a Bootstrap Navbar. The way I've implemented it so far works, but I've been trying to condense the code into one action listener for when I add my other action listeners. Also, I cannot seem to replace the attribute placeholder for the search input element when the entered value is empty:

```
var main = function(){

$('#searchStream').click(function(event) {
    $('#searchMethod').html("Streams <span class=\"caret\"></span> ");
})

$('#searchPlayer').click(function(event) {
    $('#searchMethod').html("Players <span class=\"caret\"></span> ");
})

$('$submitSearch').click(function(event){
    var searchMethod = $('#searchMethod').val();
    var method = "";

    if(searchMethod.find('Streams') == true){
        method = "Streams";
    }

    else if(searchMethod.find('Players') == true){
        method = "Players";
    }
    else if ($('#searchInput').val() == "") {
        $('input').attr("placeholder","Enter Search Term");
    }
})
}
```

Here is the HTML for the elements that use the action listeners:

```
<li><form name = "search" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>

        <!-- Search Dropdown -->
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="searchMethod">Search <span class="caret"></span> </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="searchMenu">
    <li id="searchStream"><a href="#">Streams</a></li>
    <li id="searchPlayer"><a href="#">Players</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div></li>

        <!-- Search Submit Button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">Submit</button>
    </form></li>
    </ul>
```

Here's an example of my attempt to condense the jQuery for the dropdown menu action listeners:

```
$('#searchMenu').children().click(function(event){
  var elementText = $(this).val();

  if($.contains($(this), "Streams") == true) {
    $('#searchMethod').html("Streams <span class=\"caret\"></span> ");
  }

  elseif($.contains($(this), "Players") == true) {
    $('#searchMethod').html("Players <span class=\"caret\"></span> ");
  }
})
```

I've tried using multiple implementations, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I even switched between '==' and '===' or 'elseif' and 'else if'.

Answer (score 0):

For first part with dropdown button text change you can use following code:

```
$('#searchMenu li a').on('click', function (event) {
    var elementText = $(this).text();
    $('#search-text').text(elementText);
});
```

So when you click any dropdown element you first grab it's text and then put it in dropdown button. I've wrapped dropdown button text in span element with `#search-text` id so it can be easy accessed.

As for the submit form part:

```
$('form[name="search"]').on('submit', function(event){
    var method = $('#search-text').text();

    if ($('#searchInput').val() == "") {
        $('input').attr("placeholder","Enter Search Term");
        return false;
    }
});
```

I prefer to handle form submit event instead button click, this way you also handle keybord enter key press. Your code doesn't show what you want to do with `method` variable. You probably want to pass it with form so best way to do it is put value in some hidden field.

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mxug7fqt/